# Git Repository bower install (terminal prompts disabled)

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-keys, bower-install

I try to do bower install for my project but it throws following error

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/functino/jquery-ui-touch-punch.git", exit code of #128 fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

I tried options suggested in below and from other sites but none work.

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232655/go-get-results-in-terminal-prompts-disabled-error-for-github-private-repo
```

Comment: Are you sure that URL is correct? I get a 404 for it. Also, why is this tagged with "ssh-keys"?

Comment: I changed it to `furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch` but it still tries to install =/

Comment: `bower prune` and `bower cache clean` don't seem to help. Did you ever fix this @srivat1 ?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with @functino branch: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

You can, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40916911/6309), replace your URLs with `https://<yourGitHubUsername>@github.com/xxx/arepo.git`

Make sure you have a credential helper in place (to cache the password)

```
git config credential.helper
```

Type the `git ls-remote` once (with the URL including your username), and enter your password if requested.

Then try `bower install` again.

Comment: just to clarify, without above all changes it is working fine in my other system with same user ,Is the issue related to need of any root access or problem of git? i do not have git-hub account for this project

Comment: @srivat1 yes, you did not mention anything about root in your question, but that would be enough to not have access to the same settings as your user account.

Comment: `git ls-command 
git: 'ls-command' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders Yes, `git ls-remote`, sorry. I have fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a registered bower package to a deleted git repo. I contacted the owner and it should have been resolved now [per #107](https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/issues/107)